# convert string to binary matrix with 1 bit per column

Tags: matlab

How do I convert characters from a file, e.g. 'hello' to a binary matrix like this:

```
[1  1   0  1  1  0  0 0  1 0 .......]
```

where each column of the matrix has only a 1 bit value that is 0 or 1.

All I have done so far is converted the string into the matrix of binary where each column has 7 bits of binary.

Example: 'hello'

1         1        0       1        1        0      0       0       1      0

Comment: What is the standard of conversion? ASCII?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a combination of [`dec2bin`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dec2bin.html) and [`str2num`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2num.html):

First, convert your input into a binary representation:

```
WORD = 'hello'; 

WORD_BINARY = dec2bin(WORD,7) % The 7 gives the number of bits
```

This results in:

```
WORD_BINARY =

1101000
1100101
1101100
1101100
1101111
```

This is a string, which now has to be turned into a vector:

```
for i=1:size(WORD_BINARY,1)
    for j=1:size(WORD_BINARY,2)
        WORD_OUTPUT(1,(i-1)*size(WORD_BINARY,2)+j) = str2num(WORD_BINARY(i,j))
    end
end
```

`WORD_OUTPUT` in this case is a `<1x40>` vector, starting with:

```
WORD_OUTPUT = 

[ 1     1     0     1     0     ...
```

**Edit**

If you do not want two `for` loops, you can use `reshape` first (but be aware, that reshape orders by column, not row):

```
WORD = 'hello'; 

WORD_BINARY = reshape(dec2bin(WORD,7)',1,[]);
% note the <'> after the dec2bin, to transpose the matrix

for j=1:size(WORD_BINARY,2)
    WORD_OUTPUT(1,j) = str2num(WORD_BINARY(1,j));
end
```